# Python: Convert list of tuples into a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, tuples, pack, unpack

If I have a list of tuples like the following:

```
Data = [
        #   OP,  FLAG,   IDENT,  NAME
        ( Op.GA, Flag.GA, "GA", "Asset" ),
        ( Op.LP, Flag.LP, "LP", "Low" ),
        ( Op.HP, Flag.HP, "HP", "High" ),
        ( Op.CU, Flag.CU, "CU", "Custom" ),
]
```

Is there a clever way to convert this into a list of objects so that it would be like I did the following instead:

```
Objects = [
        #       OP,    FLAG,    IDENT,  NAME
        OBJECT( Op.GA, Flag.GA, "GA", "Asset" ),
        OBJECT( Op.LP, Flag.LP, "LP", "Low" ),
        OBJECT( Op.HP, Flag.HP, "HP", "High" ),
        OBJECT( Op.CU, Flag.CU, "CU", "Custom" ),
]
```

I'm hoping for something like
`Objects = create( OBJECT, Data )`

I think I managed to figure out how to convert one element at a time using a loop and tuple unpacking (new to me). So essentially, iterate the tuple list and construct one object at a time as I append them to a second list. Is that the best way to handle this?

The reason: I'm trying to allow external code to send enum-like properties as a list of tuples, then use that to generate a list of class instances to represent enum-like data. The only reason I need classes at all is to allow external code to reference the data using named members, such as `enum_ref.Ident` (instead of `enum_ref[2]`). But maybe there is a better way to handle this type of situation?

Really appreciate any advice. I'm inexperienced with Python, so you can safely assume I don't know all of the basics.

Edit: Here is the definition of `OBJECT`. It is a custom class that can be changed however I need in order to make this work:

```
class OBJECT:

    # construct / attributes
    def __init__(self,index,value,ident,name):

        self.Index = index  # enum index or type-index
        self.Value = value  # actual value of the entry (any type)
        self.Ident = ident  # identifier string (for Blender and searching)
        self.Name = name    # display name
```

Comment: Is `OBJECT` a class you defined?

Comment: Yes, it is, I will edit with the class definition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you answered this to yourself already, instead of using a loop you can go with a list comprehension:

```
Objects = [OBJECT(*x) for x in Data]
```

<strike>Although I see the tuples in your `Data` are missing one parameter for `OBJECT` construction (the one corresponding to `desc`).</strike>

Comment: I hadn't considered using list comprehension. So better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the missing `desc`. My description strings were enormous, so I deleted that entry to avoid clutter, but forgot to do the same with my class.

Answer (score 5):

I think namedtuple is a nice minimal Python class for convenient access of attributes by name. Here how it would look like

```
from collections import namedtuple
Data = [
        #   OP,  FLAG,   IDENT,  NAME
        ( "Op.GA", "Flag.GA", "GA", "Asset" ),
        ( "Op.LP", "Flag.LP", "LP", "Low" ),
        ( "Op.HP", "Flag.HP", "HP", "High" ),
        ( "Op.CU", "Flag.CU", "CU", "Custom" ),
]

Object = namedtuple("Object", "OP FLAG IDENT NAME")
objects = [Object(*t) for t in Data]
```

After that:

```
>>> objects[0].IDENT
GA
```

PS substituted your *Op.GA* for mere strings for the sake of instantly working example.

Comment: This is new for me. I love the fact that you could let the external code define the member names to match their specific data types. I had a hard time choosing between this answer and the accepted one. I only chose the other because it was first. I don't understand why we can't have multiple accepted answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different approach with the builtin `map` function like this:

```
list_of_objects = list(map(lambda tpl: OBJECT(*tpl), Data))
```

Beaware, `map` only produces an Iterator the `list` call can not be omitted.

Comment: Really neat - I wasn't aware of the `map()` function. So it essentially calls a function for each element? This will be really useful, especially with `lambda`. If I don't use it now, I definitely will later. This is another answer I would have accepted if I could choose more than one. Really appreciate the information.